# Combining multiple stylesheets into one conditional block

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have multiple IE specific stylesheets that I need to add to my theme (combining them is not an option at this time), in addition to the standard ones. I am able to get this to work using the `wp_enqueue_style` and `$wp_styles->add_data` but each are output in it's own conditional block. Is there a way to combine them all into one?

Example Code

```
wp_enqueue_style('styles','//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css',array(),'1.0','screen and (min-width:1px)');
wp_enqueue_style('screen-medium','//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css',array(),'1.0','screen and (min-width:768px)');  
wp_enqueue_style('styles-ie8','//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css',array(),'1.0','screen');
wp_enqueue_style('screen-medium-ie8','//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css',array(),'1.0','screen');

$wp_styles->add_data('styles-ie8', 'conditional', 'lte IE 8');
$wp_styles->add_data('screen-medium-ie8', 'conditional', 'lte IE 8');
```

outputs:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='styles-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width:1px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='screen-medium-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width:768px)' />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='styles-ie8-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='screen-medium-ie8-css'  href='//previewext.3m.com/3m_theme_assets/themes/3MTheme/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<![endif]-->
```

where what I would like is...

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='styles-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width:1px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='screen-medium-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width:768px)' />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
   <link rel='stylesheet' id='styles-ie8-css'  href='//mydomain.com/assets/styles/build/screen.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
   <link rel='stylesheet' id='screen-medium-ie8-css'  href='//previewext.3m.com/3m_theme_assets/themes/3MTheme/assets/styles/build/screen_medium.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<![endif]-->
```

I tried using an array for the `$wp_styles->add_data(array('styles-ie8', 'screen-medium-ie8-css'), 'conditional', 'lte IE 8')` but that didn't work and errored out the page.

Any example I've found searching only uses one stylesheet per conditional block. I need to add about 5 or 6 with the same condition, so would ideally like to combine them, yet still use `wp_enqueue_style`.